# Error in jQuery code related to addClass and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code - fairly simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $(".location").each(function(){             
    $(this).click(function(){                 
      $("map").hide();                 
      var class = $(this).attr("data");                       
      $(".location").removeClass("activeLocation");                 
      $(this).addClass("activeLocation");                 
      $("." + class).show();             
    })         
  })     
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="locations">     
  <div class="location activeLocation" data="brian">1205 S 75th St</div>     
  <div class="location one" data="mark">6603 A Royal Street</div>     
  <div class="location" data="dan">4725 Merle Hay Rd</div>     
  <div class="location" data="andy">62 Soccer Park Road</div>     
  <div id="mapviewer" class="brian map">Map to 1205 S 75th Street</div>     
  <div style="display: none;" id="mapviewer" class="mark map">Map to 6603 A Royal Street</div>     
  <div style="display: none;" id="mapviewer" class="dan map">Map to 4725 Merle Hay Rd</div>    
  <div style="display: none;" id="mapviewer" class="andy map">Map to  62 Soccer Park Road</div>
</div>
```

Everything works if I comment out two lines:

```
var class = $(this).attr("data");
$("." + class).show();
```

Without these two lines commented, no action at all. These two lines of code look OK to me.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after the line

```
var class = $(this).attr("data");
```

do

```
console.log(class)
```

to see what it contains. Additionally you do not have to wrap this all in an each() function, just change the first line to

```
$('.location').click(function() {...
```

all of the this's within the function will be this `.location` object

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a [reserved word (for future use) *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). Use another variable name (such as `cls`).

---

Also, instead of using custom HTML attributes, you should use [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code was modified like as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $(".location").each(function(){             
    $(this).click(function(){                 
      $(".map").hide();  // <--- here you wrote map").hide()
      var cls = $(this).attr("data");     // <--- at Felix Kling advice           
      $(".location").removeClass("activeLocation");                 
      $(this).addClass("activeLocation");                 
      $("." + cls).show();     // <---- at Felix Kling adive
    })         
  })     
});
```

Please avoid reserved keywords from languages which you use (php, asp.net, etc.) or keywords from OOP field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".location").on('click', function(){             
  $(".map").hide();                 
  $(".location").removeClass("activeLocation");                 
  $(this).addClass("activeLocation");                 
  $("." + $(this).attr("data")).show();             
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vUsjY/)